# Dotnet packages and appsettings

Tags: c#, .net-core

Our source directory is getting cluttered with various appsettings files that we use for specific area of our app based on functionality. We know we can build a single appsettings file but prefer to have them segregated this way.

Now, some of these appsettings are also needed in multiple apps. In this case, we are currently copying the appsettings to multiple directories and we see this as a huge maintenance nightmare when any appsettings need to be modified.

If there a way to have a single set and include this in each of our apps, essentially a universal appsettings project where only appsettings and configuration models are in the project, and have them loaded by each app? We will load them into configuration models at run-time.

Some of our apps are .NetStd 2.0, some .Net-core 2.0, some Framework 4.7.2.

Comment: All .NET Core applications, whether they're part of a package or not, read from `IConfiguration`, not any settings files. There's nothing special about `appsettings.json`, that's just the default name for a JSON settings file. You can add multiple such files in your main configuration, include environment variables, command line parameters, database rows etc. In fact, by default both environment variables and cli parameters are already configured and override the settings in `appsettings.json`

Comment: `these appsettings are also needed in multiple apps` instead of copying these around, store them in a central JSON file and use `AddJson` to load it.

Comment: You can easily split by functionality too, if each feature/module uses a separate section. All configuration sources are merged, with newer sources overriding previous ones. You can easily split and store settings by feature in files, databases or configuration services

Comment: The issue is having this in a centralized project that can be added to each app. When the app is built, would the file(s) be in the same directory as the executable?

Comment: You don't need that at all. Just a call to `AddJson(thatPath)`. The path itself could come from a settings file loaded in host configuration, or an environment variable. Settings aren't deployed in packages or projects, they can be loaded from any configured source.

Comment: `would the file(s) be in the same directory as the executable` doesn't matter. .NET Core configuration doesn't use `app.config` files. There's really-really nothing special about `appsettings.json`. You could load all JSON files found in a folder if you like, by calling `AddJsonFile` in a loop.

Comment: I think I'm beginning to understand how this can be done now. Post an answer and I'll accept it